# How find this value $\frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{a+c-b}+\frac{c}{a+b-c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $a,b,c$ such
$$\dfrac{a^2}{b+c-a}+\dfrac{b^2}{a+c-b}+\dfrac{c^2}{a+b-c}=0$$

Prove that:
$$F(a,b,c)=\dfrac{a}{b+c-a}+\dfrac{b}{a+c-b}+\dfrac{c}{a+b-c}=1 \text{or}-\dfrac{3}{2}$$

maybe can use 
$$\dfrac{a^2}{b+c-a}+a+\dfrac{b^2}{a+c-b}+b+\dfrac{c^2}{a+b-c}+c=a+b+c$$
$$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{ab+ac}{b+c-a}+\dfrac{ba+bc}{a+c-b}+\dfrac{ac+bc}{a+b-c}=0$$
maybe we can have $a+b+c=0?$

Comment: How is this a calculus problem? Looks like an algebra problem to me.

Comment: Do you have a reason to think there is a solution?  You have one equation in three unknowns, so one would expect a 2D space of solutions.  You are asking that $F(a,b,c)$ be constant over that space.  If you trust the problem setter to make sure there is an answer, you can find any solution to the equation and evaluate $F$

Comment: such this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581884/how-prove-this-fracabc-a22-fracbca-b22-fraccab-c22-0?rq=1

Comment: Problems like this have to be carefully prepared to have an answer.  The one you link to was prepared this way.  Otherwise the solution space argument applies.

Comment: No,This problem have result: it is $1$ or $-\dfrac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

There is no answer.  I arbitrarily chose $b=1,c=2$ and [solved for $a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20x%5E2%2F%283-x%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B4%2F%28x-1%29%3D0). Alpha returned four solutions, among them $-3$ and $1-2^{(2/3)}$.  Evaluating your expression gives [$1$ for $1-2^{(2/3)}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F%283-x%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B2%2F%28x-1%29%20with%20x%3D%281-2%5E%282%2F3%29%29)  and [$\frac 32$ for $-3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F%283-x%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B2%2F%28x-1%29%20with%20x%3D-3)

Comment: No,This problem have value,

Answer (score 0):

hint: the given condition is equivalent to $$- \left( a+b+c \right)  \left( {a}^{3}-b{a}^{2}-c{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}a+4\,c
ba-{c}^{2}a+{b}^{3}-{b}^{2}c-b{c}^{2}+{c}^{3} \right) 
=0$$